# Angular.to JSON not allowing % as parameter

Tags: json, angularjs, character-encoding, uri, encode

I am trying to send some Angular object through JSON.

I tried this.

```
$scope.dkPrintData=function(){
$scope.myData={name:'Ramesh',class:'XII',Marks:'90%'};
$http.get('dkStudnet.do?method=JsonData&Student='+ angular.toJson($scope.myData))
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

 });
```

If I removed `%` symbol in the `$scope.MyData` object it is working fine but it is not accepting special charters like `%`.

Comment: a stringifyed json as get parameter looks very strange. you should consider using post: $http.post('dkStudnet.do', $scope.myData) and it will work like a charm... % is a special character in urls so it gets escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'dkStudnet.do?method=JsonData&Student='+ encodeURIComponent(angular.toJson($scope.myData))
```

Comment: you should flesh out your answer.

Comment: Thanks encodeURIComponent now Working fine. But not accepting Larger data. Is there any way to set Larger Data

Comment: you should use POST if you're sending more than few kilobytes.

Comment: @MatjazLipus : I have to call a WebAPI method from angular http with arguments containing [.,/,\,-,?] etc. when I pass the string argument containing these symbols, http doesn't call my API method. Can you suggest any workaround for that?